# How is it possible to receive an order charged with 0$? Google Developer Console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, developer-console, google-pay

For the first time I have received a new order payment on my google console developer account with no charge. I mean the user got charged for 0$ and the price should be 10$. Is this a bug or what? Should I cancel the user subscription?
Would appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: Hachem did you get a solution to this problem? I've just experienced this and I don't see any guidance on the internet. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If it is a subscription user might be make upgrade/downgrade on its subscription so if you didn't set proration mode on upgrade(not available for downgrade.) will not be charged for more information check [Add Subscription](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#Allow-upgrade) defined under headline "set proration mode."

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that your subscription offers free trial. In that case you will see an order for 0.00$ when user subscribes, and an actual amount charged (as a separate order) after the trial expires.

Then if you search with user email in your play console order management, you should be able to see both orders.